# How to suppress Windows CMD "Start" error message?

Tags: windows, cmd, system-error

The Windows command "Start" issues a system message requiring user confirmation if the targeted process.ext does not exist.

```
Start no_such_process.exe
```

Results in the system message ...

*Windows cannot find 'no_such_process.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.*

Is there any way to suppress this message? I'm doing my own error handling.

I've redirected "Start" 1>NUL 2>NUL but that didn't help.

A similar question was posed back in '09 but there was no workable answer then.

Comment: > help start, the entire documentation is in it.

Comment: Just check whether the executable exists before calling `start`.

Comment: Note that the first quoted argument is the window title; you should never omit it to not confuse `start`; the title can be empty: `start "" /OPTIONS command_line`

Comment: Kornflexx -- I've checked the START documentation from several sources and there is nothing about suppressing the message.

Harry Johnston -- I'm well aware of the IF EXIST filename feature. But, what if I don't know where the executable is located? Like, in one of the many folders in the PATH variable. IF EXIST doesn't search the PATH.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution? I really need this